How to install the HCL or LCh Color Space for Blender's Compositor (for use in the Separate and Combine Color nodes)
I am working on a project within Blender that involves colouring black and white videos, and part of it involves using the "Separate" and "Combine" color nodes to overlay the color masks I created over the original footage. That said, I'm generally not satisfied with my results, and I wonder if there is a way to install the HCL (Hue-Chroma-Luminance) or LCh color space within Blender's compositor, so that I may get the results I'm looking for were I using other software like GIMP or Photoshop? Is there a way to recreate the "separate" and "combine" color nodes within Blender's scripting interface where I could add the HCL/LCh color space?
